# C# Entity Framework complex join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join, left-join

Trying to figure this out since last 5 hours but couldn't find any solution.

Basically I am trying to create an excel with ExcelPackage from below data

```
Table1
    ID    Name
    1      t1_1
    2      t1_2


Table2
    ID    Name
    1      t2_1
    2      t2_2


Table12
    ID    Table1   Table2   Value
    1      1         1       v11
    2      2         2       v12
```

from this trying to get any of the following

```
Table1Name, t2_1, t2_2
t1_1,       v11 ,
t1_2,           , v12
```

is there a way in EF to get row in this format? Where I am stuck is for each record in Table1 I want to get all record of Table2 with Value (from Table12) null if empty without repeating Table1 record (kind of turning rows of Table12 into columns of Table1).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var info = (from t1 in Table1                
            from t2 in Table2
            join t120 in Table12 
            on new {Table1 = t1.ID, Table2 = t2.ID} equals new {t120.Table1, t120.Table2} into t12s
            from t12 in t12s.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { t2, t12 } by new { t1.ID, t1.Name } into sub
            select new 
            {
                sub.Key.Name,
                data = sub.Select(x => new { x.t2.Name, x.t12 == null ? null : x.t12.Value }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

foreach(var item in info)
{
    Console.Write($"{item.Name}\t");
    foreach(sub in item.data.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
        Console.Write($"{sub.Name}:{sub.Value}\t");
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: says t1.Name does not exist in current context in side select new { ...  }

Comment: assume that should be sub.key

Comment: @Bhavesh You right, also I updated answer to left join.

Comment: it doesn't return null/empty/default for Table12 record that doesn't join with Table1.

in above example , it returns
t1_1,       v11  instead of t1_1,v11,(here is default/null)
t1_2,v12    instead of t1_2,(here is default/null) , v12

Comment: that's the complexity, is there a way to do that with left join?

Comment: Try updated answer, now it returns all data, including _null/empty/default_ with left join.

Comment: works now, I have update your answer to change grouping by Table1.ID instead of. Grouping by Name will repeat t12 if there are multiple records in Table1 with same name.

Thanks